# Не выполняется подготовленный запрос

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Почему нельзя выполнить команду

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("CREATE TABLE table1(ID int not null auto_increment primary key)");
$STH->execute();
```

А функцией

```
$DBH->exec("CREATE TABLE table1(ID int not null auto_increment primary key)");
```

выполняется без каких либо проблем.

Можете объяснить почему?)

> P.S. $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $user, $pass);

Comment: Наверняка вам возвращают ошибку(с объяснением) после вызова `$DBH->prepare("CREATE ...`.

Comment: Что значит нельзя? Вам ошибка какая-то выводится или что?

Comment: Никакая ошибка не выводится. Вопрос в этом. Просто пустой лист (или если есть `echo`  выводит его)

Comment: Пробовал написать и в `try {} catch (PDOException $e) ...` и без него.

Comment: Подавление ошибок отключали?

Comment: конечно же нет, не отключал

Answer (score 1):

**Документация по MySQL**

[SQL Syntax Allowed in Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html#idm140121905425232)

Тут или драйвер не поддерживает(безопастность). Или надо хоть одну переменную передать.